# Remove Parent Category from Child Category URL

Tags: categories, htaccess, 404-error

I am trying to remove parent category from the child category but each attempt returns a 404 error.

Main Category Link ([Displays All India Recruitment](http://www.governmentjobsvacancies.com/all-india-recruitment/))

Child Category Link ([Displays Sub-Category](http://www.governmentjobsvacancies.com/all-india-recruitment/deputy-chief-mechanical-engineer/))

**What am i looking for specifically**

- I want my category hierarchy to remain intact when viewing category
  in the sidebars. However, I wish to remove the parent category from
  the child category in URL ONLY.

For example.

I want my child category link to have url structure as given below

```
www.governmentjobsvacancies.com/deputy-chief-mechanical-engineer/
```

Existing Format

```
www.governmentjobsvacancies.com/all-india-recruitment/deputy-chief-mechanical-engineer/
```

Please let me know if this is possible. I have tried multiple plugins and recommendations on various websites but each option returns 404 error.

I am hopeful, I will get some good help from wp experts.

**My WP Version:4.5.1**

Comment: You could just set custom permalinks for your categories with [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/).

Comment: Does the category belong to a custom taxonomy or default category taxonomy?