# How To Remove Parent Category from Child Category URL?

Tags: categories

Are there no easy way to ensure that the permalinks only have the lowest child-category listed? Do I really need to install a plugin for this or make custom code? I already use RankMath to strip the category base, but hoped I could also force it to include the lowest child-category in URL.

Example of my current (unwanted) child category URL now: [www.website.com/parent-cat/child-cat/](http://www.website.com/parent-cat/child-cat/)
Example of my requested (needed) category URL now: [www.website.com/child-cat/](http://www.website.com/child-cat/)

I need to make sure that the possible implementation is friendly in future wordpress updates.

I have already read these threads:

- [Remove parent category from permalink? Basically only have the child category?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6106/remove-parent-category-from-permalink-basically-only-have-the-child-category)
- [Remove Parent Category from Child Category URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225838/remove-parent-category-from-child-category-url)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.